# Which web browsers natively support Array.forEach()

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Which browsers other than Firefox support Array.forEach()?  [Mozilla say it's an extension to the standard](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:Array:forEach#Compatibility) and I realise it's trivial to add to the array prototype, I'm just wondering what other browsers support it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) article of Wikipedia lists the JS versions by browser. forEach is [part of JavaScript 1.6](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6). So it is supported indeed by most browsers, except Opera 9.02 (which I just tested). Opera 9.5 (which I just installed!) supports it, along with indexOf for Array.

Surprisingly, it is not official. I don't see its support in the page [ECMAScript support in Opera 9.5](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera95/js/ecma/). Perhaps it is an overlook or perhaps only a partial support they don't want to advertise.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't list the versions anymore, and I can't find a full list in any of the articles.

Answer (score 20):

I just checked this for another question: [JavaScript for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for/6442930#6442930).

On kangax's [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), Array.forEach gets a 'yes' for all browsers except IE8.

As of September 2011, IE browser share on desktop devices is [less than 40%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_table), and [at least 8% of browsers are IE 9](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0).

In other words, Array.forEach is now supported by around 70% of desktop browsers. Obviously, this figure varies considerably, depending on territory and other factors -- some regions or countries (such as Brasil) have a higher proportion of Chrome users, for example, and some (such as China) have far more users on IE6 and IE8.

I haven't checked, but mobile support (on WebKit and Opera browsers) may be even higher.

Comment: Which is still enough to be a problem in this day and age :-( go for jquery each instead.

Answer (score 12):

Since IE doesn't support it (not even v8), I use jQuery.each() -- http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each

Comment: v8 = version 8. V8 = Google V8.

Comment: For IE8 compatibility use: `for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {}` cycle instead.

Comment: The best option is to avoid Array.forEach indeed, since we know not all browsers support it

Comment: or define it by yourselves: http://smthngsmwhr.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/higher-order-javascript-short-journey-into-the-land-of-functional-programming/

Answer (score 4):

All modern browsers but IE.

Comment: So, that is: "All modern browsers."

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft AJAX client library adds this to the Array prototype so if you have that client library in your site then you'll have it for sure.

Comment: Does this change the Array implementation in IE? last time I checked, extending the Array object in IE failed.

Comment: I'd think so, I hardly think the MS AJAX team would make IE break :P

Answer (score 0):

If you need all browsers to support this and other JavaScript 1.6 to 1.8 functions, I would suggest using the customizable [jPaq](http://jpaq.org/) library.  The functions are implemented in the way that was suggested by Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) and it looks like all browsers support `foreach` except **Opera Mini** which has support info as `?Support unknow`. If you're interested you can use this link to check the browser support for any features. https://caniuse.com/?search=foreach