# JavaScript: For...Each / With

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript foreach Vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for)

What's the difference between a for loop and for...in? I mean, if there is a difference, it can't be much.

And, I see within validation scripts sometimes the function written like:

```
function check() {
    with(something) {
        if(){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

What's the point of the "with" condition?

Answer (score 15):

The [`for each..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) statement iterates a specified variable over all values of an object's properties. For each distinct property, a specified statement is executed. This was introduced by Mozilla in JavaScript 1.6 (see comment by [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) below), and is not supported in all mainstream browsers.

For each example:

```
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8};
for each (var item in obj) {
  sum += item;
}
console.log(sum); // prints "26", which is 5 + 13 + 8
```

A similar statement is [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), which iterates over the property names instead of property values. The same example written using `for..in`:

```
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8};
for (var prop in obj) {
  sum += obj[prop];
}
console.log(sum); // prints "26", which is 5 + 13 + 8
```

The `for..in` statement has been around since JavaScript 1.0, so you're safe to use it in all browsers.

These statements are different from the traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, since they are used to iterate over the properties of an object. A `for` loop can be used to iterate over the elements of an array, but it cannot be used to iterate over the properties of an object, unless you can use ECMAScript 5's [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which could be used to implement the above example as follows:

```
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8};
var keys = Object.keys(obj)
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  sum += obj[keys[i]];
}
console.log(sum); // prints "26", which is 5 + 13 + 8
```

---

As for the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement, note the following:

> JavaScript looks up an unqualified name by searching a scope chain associated with the execution context of the script or function containing that unqualified name. The 'with' statement adds the given object to the head of this scope chain during the evaluation of its statement body. If an unqualified name used in the body matches a property in the scope chain, then the name is bound to the property and the object containing the property. Otherwise a 'ReferenceError' is thrown.

Therefore, consider the following:

```
var prop1 = 10;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8};

with (obj) {
   console.log(prop1); // prints 5 instead of 10
}
```

Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode). The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

Comment: for...in, for each...in? as opposed to a for loop? still doesn't make much sense why i wouldn't just just a regular loop do do any of that.

Comment: I guess I really need to see a practical side-by-side comparison. I've been looping through JSON objects with loops and inner loops.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about `for each ... in`. It can be considered as a *Mozilla extension*, as you say, implemented on *JavaScript(TM) 1.6* ( JavaScript(TM) === Mozilla ;), but it is actually part of the [ECMAScript for XML Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-357.htm) (ECMA-357), which is implemented only on Mozilla engines. That's why is not available in other implementations, it has *nothing to do* with the ECMA-262 Standard, again, it will only work on Rhino and SpiderMonkey.

Comment: Also, for each...in has been deprecated by Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

[`for each (var i in obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) iterates over the **values** of an object while `for(var i in obj)` iterates over the properties. Use it for objects only!

You need a `for...in...` loop to iterate over properties of an object.  A normal `for` loop would not help you here.

---

The [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement pushes the properties of the provided object at the beginning of the scope chain. In your example, if `something` has a property `foo`, then you can access this property *inside* the `with` body just with `foo` (instead of `something.foo`).
But note that all other variables, like local variables are now farther down the scope chain, which makes accessing them potentially slower.

Most books and experts recommend [to not use `with`.](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/)

Comment: It's interesting... I would never have wanted to use the "with" statement. I just needed to understand why it was created. So apparently I was just fine in my ignorance. If I need to reference something directly, just pass it into the function...