# Safest way to loop over JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object to hold a bunch of properties like

```
var o = {x: 20, y: 40, color: 'red'};
```

More properties can be added to the object throughout its life, so I would like a generic way to loop over the properties to set them later. I know if the `Object.prototype` has been messed with, simply

```
for(var prop in o) { ... }
```

will cause its properties to also be looped over. What other things can cause this to mess up, and what is the safest way to loop like this?

Comment: Take a look at [this post][1], you pretty much said it in your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for

Comment: @Davis if you follow the link from George P pay attention to the answer by Bno because it, and not the accepted answer, mentions the `hasOwnProperty` technique which saves you from the case in which `Object.prototype` has been messed with, and is considered a best practice, at least by *Good Parts* adherents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all of the properties on an object, then inherited properties are the only real problem you have to deal with. [The `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) can be used to confirm that a property exists directly an object, and isn't just inherited.

```js
Object.prototype.example = 2;
var o = {x: 4, y: 6};

for (var prop in o) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, prop)) {
        console.log(o[prop]);
    }
}
```

This will print all of the properties of the object itself, but it won't print the inherited `.example`.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to what @Jeremy Banks suggested, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method does return only "own" property names of an object, too. Hence an ES5 solution:

```
var o = { x: 20, y: 40, color: 'red' };

Object.keys(o).forEach(function (prop) { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use object.hasOwnProperty()

```
var buz = {
    fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
    if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        alert("this is fog (" + name + ") for sure. Value: " + buz[name]);
    }
    else {
        alert(name); // toString or something else
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Example.3a_Iterating_over_the_properties_of_an_object