# for i of foo is returning extra keys?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am calling this on an array with 3 objects in it. It ends up returning the correct keys in addition to these extra keys...

`unique
last
truncate
random
include
contains
any`

Why?

Comment: Why not just use a normal for or while loop?

Comment: Maybe those are added to the object's prototype? In JavaScript you have to use: for i in foo { if (foo.hasOwnProperty(i)){...} }, not sure how node.js / coffeescript supports this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting those extra properties because you, or a library you're using, has extended the `Array` prototype. As Mike points out in his answer, you can skip those by using `hasOwnProperty`. Indeed, CoffeeScript has an `own` keyword built in that does this for you:

```
for own i of foo
  obj = foo[i]
  ...
```

But, as Mike also points out in his answer, it's more efficient to loop through an array by incrementing a counter rather than iterating over the keys. To do that, you'd use CoffeeScript's `for...in`  syntax:

```
for obj in foo
  ...
```

(If you need indices in the loop as well, you can write `for obj, i in foo`.)

Comment: Ahh, great to know, understand it all now. Didn't totally understand CoffeeScripts `in` before. Knowing `for own` is great too.

Answer (score 3):

`for (... in ...)` will return things on the object's prototype.  See [JavaScript for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for/6443017#6443017)

The best solution is to iterate over array elements using an index loop

```
for (var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i) { ... }
```

This has the benefit of getting a numeric key instead of a string and reliably iterating in order.

Alternatively, you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to make sure you don't get keys from the prototype.

```
for (var k in obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) { continue; }
  ...
}
```

or a variation if you're worried about `hasOwnProperty` being a overridden.

Even more alternatively, you can define these prototype properties as `enumerable: false` using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: @Mike Probably because your answer is about JavaScript, and the question was about CoffeeScript. (I didn't downvote you, though. Your answer is certainly useful.)

Comment: @Trevor, thanks for the response.  CoffeeScript is certainly a separate language, but like most languages that start off compiling to another language early adopters have to understand details of the underlying language -- early adopters of C couldn't use it without understanding a bit of the native instruction set to which it compiled, and early adopters of Scala couldn't get by without knowing about Java or the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Mike, useful to understand the underlying concept. My main hiccup was misunderstanding how CoffeeScript implemented `of` and `in` differently.