# get collection of elements

Tags: jquery

how to get a collection of elements?

```
var tst = this.tbl_list.find('col');
alert('length = '+tst.length);
for(var key in tst){
    alert(tst[key][0].tagName);
}
```

this alerts `length = 7` (which is the correct count), but each element is `undefined`!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you're using `for in`, you're iterating over all the jQuery methods as well (`find`, `children` etc); and none of these have `[0].tagName` (for more info as to *why* see [JavaScript for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for)).

Instead, you should either use `each()`, or use a `for (;;;)` loop;

```
var tst = this.tbl_list.find('col');
alert('length = '+tst.length);
for(var i=0;i<tst.length;i++){
    alert(tst[i].tagName);
}
```

You can see the difference in using them in this JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/nTCSY/

Using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each), you'd have;

```
tst.each(function () {
    alert(this.tagName);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing your mark-up, but something like this should work -

```
tst.each(function() {
   alert(this.tagName)
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/UjfUy/1/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like so (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
var elements = this.tbl_list.find('col'); 

$.each(elements, function(index, element){
   alert(element.tagName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tst = this.tbl_list.find('col');
alert('length = '+tst.length);
for(var i=0;i<tst.length;i++){
    alert(tst[i].tagName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)  to get single elements from the collection of dom objects.

```
var tst = this.tbl_list.find('col');

alert('length = '+ tst.length);
for(i=0; i< tst.length ; i++  ){
   alert(tst.get(i).tagName);

 //or tst.eq(i)
}
```

another way is [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iterate through dom elements.

```
.each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise .
```

e.g.

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

for your solution this should be like this:

```
tst.each(function() {
   alert(this.tagName)
});
```