# Can this be written much more simplistically using a foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function GetDiagrams(componentID) {
    $.getJSON("../PlanView/GetDiagrams", { ComponentID: componentID }, function (diagrams) {
        for (var i = 0; i < diagrams.length; i++) {
            PaintDiagram(diagrams[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

All I am doing is calling PaintDiagram on each element returned. I tried Googling for a bit because I am pretty confident this is easily reducible, but was not able to pull up a quick example.

Is this function a candidate for any more refactoring?

Comment: What you have above would be the fastest, also i don't see any need to refactor a simple for loop.

Comment: Check out this question (and answers) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-foreach-vs-for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I opted to leave my solution as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I would definitely use the jquery `$.each`

```
 $.getJSON("../PlanView/GetDiagrams", { ComponentID: componentID }, function (diagrams) {
     $.each(diagrams, function() {
         PaintDiagram(this);
     });
 });
```

Comment: If you really want to go there, why not omit the args and say `PaintDiagram(this)`? (`each` binds each iteration's context to the object)

Comment: $.each is actually slower than for..in

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off.  `$.each(diagrams, function(){ PaintDiagram(this); });`.  I fixed it for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetDiagrams(componentID) {
    $.getJSON("../PlanView/GetDiagrams", { ComponentID: componentID }, function (diagrams) {
    for (i in diagrams) {
        PaintDiagram(diagrams[i]);
    }
    });
}
```

This is pretty much as good as you can do with js since it doesn't have a foreach

Comment: @pete No, the i will be the key in the diagrams array

Comment: I suggest checking `if(diagrams.hasOwnProperty(i))` to make sure you're not getting a property from the prototype chain.