# What is the different between for loop and for in loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript for…in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for)

I am using a for loop in my function. I use both type of loops, "`for in`" and "`for`". Both are producing the same result so I want to know what is the difference between these loops and how to know which loop should be used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jam = ['amit','sam','ram','soly']
for(var i in jam){
alert(jam[i])
}
//for (i=0; i<jam.length; i++) {
//  jam[i]
//alert(jam[i].length)
//}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need. I usually use for-in loop because it is a shorter form, but sometimes you may want to have control over the iteration variable. For instance, if you want to iterate over *even* indices, you'd need to use the normal for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i+=2) {...}
```

The same applies, for example, if you want to iterate backwards:

```
for (var i = myarray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {...}
```

Certainly, for objects, the for-in loop allows you to get the property name in the iteration variable. For example:

```
var myobject = {year: 1992, city: "Barcelona"}
for (var propname in myobject) alert(propname + " = " + myobject[propname]);
```

In your example, I'd use for-in because you are doing a simple iteration. Moreover I think in a non-optimized Javascript compiler/interpreter, the for-in loop would be even faster because variable increment is done internally (i.e. it is not a Javascript statement such as "i++").

Comment: Some variable that has been assigned to an object key value outside the for-loop could not be found inside this loop, therefore I would recommend to use for-in-loop in that case.

Answer (score 2):

you can use whichever you understood clearly. for arrays you can use both the cases.

for arrays you can use

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  //do something
}
```

for objects you can use

```
for ( var i in obj){
  //do something
}
```

as you cannot get the length of object.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops are meant to `iterate` while incrementing/decrementing.

```
// note that I'm making this big and ugly to show what's going on
var incrementor = 1, length = 10,
    array = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
              "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" ];

for (; incrementor <= length; incrementor = incrementor + 1) {
    console.log(incrementor);  // 1,2,3,...,10
    console.log( array[incrementor - 1] );  // "one", "two", "three", ..., "ten"
}
```

`for ... in ...` loops are meant to `enumerate` through object properties.

```
var object = { "key1" : "one", "key2" : "two", "key3" : "three" },
    key = "";

for (key in object) {
    console.log(key); // "key1", "key2", "key3"
    console.log( object[key] ); // "one", "two", "three"
}
```

The reason you use `for` for arrays is because on bad browsers, `for ... in ...` can include not only the number properties (ie: `key=0, key=1,...`), but it can also enumerate through things you don't want it to...  ...like `key=splice, key=length, key=unshift`.
Not really a good thing if you're running this code on a professional site, or for specialized versions of JS being run on specific hardware, or being run as a scripting language in a program like Unity or Unreal Editor's UnrealScript.

The reason you don't use an `iterator` on objects is because you don't normally make objects like:

```
var obj = { "0" : "zero", "1" : "one", "2" : "two" };
```

And even if you did (jQuery does something like this, for example), there might be word-based properties that you want to enumerate over, but you can't, because you're counting.

Also important to note: `enumerating` with `for ... in ...` isn't standardized in its functionality.
What this means is that it's not 100% guaranteed to spit the values out in the order you're expecting them in.
If you're relying on your loop going `0,1,2,3,...` then `for ... in ...` can't guarantee that 100% of the browsers will do it that way, 100% of the time - even if most browsers get it right most of the time.

Most-frequently, they go by the first-in, first-out rule, now.
If you build your object like `{ one : 1, two : 2, three : 3 }`, any modern browser will print `1,2,3`.  If you build your object like: `{ two: 2, one: 1, six: 6 }`, you'll get `2,1,6`.

But that's a 95% of the time "should", not a 100% of the time "will".