# JavaScript alternative to "for each" loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

According to the MDN page at [for each...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in), this construct is deprecated. Is there an alternative that does exactly the same thing? The [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) does not iterate over non-integer (own enumerable) properties. If there isn't an alternative, why did they deprecate it then?

Comment: Good point [made here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an alternative that does exactly the same thing?

A `for ... in` loop in which the first thing you do in the block of code is to copy `foo[propertyname]` to a variable.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is only this work-around, which isn't really a language replacement for "for each". So they shouldn't have deprecated it, right?

Comment: @Benedictus — No. It's in JavaScript 1.0. Netscape 2 supports it!

Answer (score 17):

To iterate over all the properties of an object `obj`, you may do this :

```
for (var key in obj) {
   console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

If you want to avoid inherited properties, you may do this :

```
for (var key in obj) {
   if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
   console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can make use of the new **ECMAScript 5th Edition** functions:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: ^ this is how I solved the `no-restricted-syntax` error from eslint when the `forinstatement` is used.