# Iterating over objects in a JSON array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to rewrite a .php multi-dimentional array and foreach loop (the one used in the "Sponsor Flip Wall" jQuery example found at http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/) in JSON/JavaScript, as unfortunately the Web host I am being forced to use does not have PHP support.

The array originally looked as follows:

```
$sponsors = array(
array('facebook','The biggest social network in the world.','http://www.facebook.com/'),
array('adobe','The leading software developer targeted at web designers and developers.','http://www.adobe.com/'),
array('microsoft','One of the top software companies of the world.','http://www.microsoft.com/')
);
```

and I now have the following:

```
var sponsors = [
    { "name": "facebook", "description": "The biggest social network in the world.", "website": "http://www.facebook.com/" },
    { "name": "adobe", "description": "The leading software developer targeted at web designers and developers.", "website": "http://www.adobe.com/" },
    { "name": "microsoft", "description": "One of the top software companies of the world.", "website": "http://www.microsoft.com/" },
];
```

However I am stumped at the foreach loop, as I don't believe JavaScript has a direct comparison? Upon research, it seems I will either need to use the jQuery *$.each* or for loops within for loops.

I was looking at the answer to [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-to-iterate-over-a-json-structure) but is seems that their array only contains two values - an object and a key. Mine has multiple fields per object so I don't think it completely applies? Or if it does, I don't know how to expand upon it?

The .php foreach loop I am trying to recreate:

```
foreach($sponsors as $company)
    {
        echo $company[0] . ":" . $company[1] . "(" . $company[2] . ")"; //eg.
    }
```

Any ideas?  (I would prefer my answer was written purely in JavaScript as opposed to jQuery, if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
for( var i = 0; i < sponsors.length; i++) {
    var sponsor = sponsors[i];
    document.writeln(sponsor.name + ":" + sponsor.description + "(" + sponsor.website + ")");        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( var i = 0; i < sponsors.length; i++) {
    var sponsor = sponsors[i];
    console.log(sponsor.name);
}
```

Using a standard for loop will work well, providing you know the key names for the data!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sponsors.forEach(function(sp) {
    console.log(sp.name);
    console.log(sp.description);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget
`for (var i = ...`
and
`for i in ...`and use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)
It works in all browsers and is easy to use. So just use for example `_.each()`:

```
_(array).each(function(item) {
  // Works everywhere
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this question and answer here, very similar to what you are asking.

[JavaScript alternative to "for each" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637289/javascript-alternative-to-for-each-loop)