# C++ memset() equivalent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, c++, memset

I have worked in C++ with `memset()` and definitely this function need not to be introduced here.Now I want to know what is the `memset()` equivalent function in jQuery? I searched the internet but can't find anything.Is there any equivalent function in jquery yet?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have pointers and doesn't allow you to access an object's underlying binary representation directly, so there is no equivalent of `memset`. You could traverse all your object's members and set them to `null`, but that's a very different flavour of mutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to know what is the memset() equivalent function in jQuery?

There is no javascript equivalent to `memset`. `memset` is a low level C function, whose implementation and interface rely on the fact that you have access to both the address and the memory representation of a variable.

None of these two preconditions are valid for javascript. You could implement something that sets an object's internals to null and zero (based on reflection/metadata), but that's quite a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `memset()` is a function that can be used to initialize an array or other object in a simple, brute-force kind of way.  There are cases when using JavaScript that you want to do essentially the same thing.

Here are a few examples of how you might define such a function.  Each line will get the job done when passed a simple array.  Some of these may work with other object types as well.  The first line (`jQuery.each`) may be the most efficient and generically useful (assuming you have jQuery).

```
function memset( object, value )
   {
   jQuery.each( object, function(i,v){ object[i]=value; } );
// jQuery(object).each( function(i,v){ object[i]=value; } );
// for ( var i=0; i<object.length; i++ ) object[i]=value;
// for ( var i in object ) object[Number(i)]=value;
   }
```

As with C++, this `memset()` is a low-level operation, and it use should be limited to objects that are essentially "[plain-old-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)" -- simple arrays being the prime example.

Additional reading:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each
- http://api.jquery.com/each
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229010/86967
- [What are POD types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)