# Declaring a callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, callback

While I was at home playing some *Javascriptz* and, I faced something...

I made a simple function that returns each char from a string or each position value from an array:

```
function each (haystack, callback) {
    var each;
    for (each in haystack){
        if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
            callback (haystack[each]);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
each ("StackOverflow", function (c) {
    console.log(c);
});
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could turn /\ that, into this:

```
each ("StackOverflow", c) {
    console.log(c);
}
```

Or at least something *like* this, anything that you don't need to rewrite the word `function` for the callback.

I tried this, but with no success:

```
each ("StackOverflow",
    "console.log(c)" // turn the callback function into a string
    // but where was `c` defined here? do.not.ask.me.
);
```

And the `each()` was:

```
function each (haystack, callback) {
    var each;
    for (each in haystack){
        // call it in a setTimeout() crazy? yeah, didn't work...
        setTimeout(callback, 0);

        //and also tried this, no success...
        var b = new Function ("haystack[each]", cb);
        b ();
    }
}
```

My conclusion here is, unfortunately we can't have a callback function without declaring an anonymous function.

**Is there a way I can make a callback function without using the work** `function`?

Comment: What is your question, really? And why do you want to avoid writing word "function"?

Comment: The only thing this would achieve is compromising readability.

Comment: Have you ever seen Coffee Script?

Comment: I mention it because it sounds like you might like it -- it's a similar but syntactically cleaner language that compiles to Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You could adopt a compile-to-javascript language like [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org) that has a shorter syntax for anonymous functions:

```
//javascript version
function(c){ console.log(c) }

//coffeescript version
(c) => console.log c
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to declare the function somewhere, be it 'in-place' (anonymous functions) or just somewhere else in your code as a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Please forget the string representation version, it always involves `eval()`, which we know is evil.

You can't simply change the syntax of a programming language.

Writing `function () {}` is not really a big nuisance anyways, you can even configure your editor to insert the snippet automatically. You can also use CoffeeScript, which has an easier syntax for functions (besides several other features of course) and compiles to Javascript.

Also, you don't HAVE TO use an anonymous function. You can pass any kind of function.

```
var func = function (x) { console.log(x); }; //inline function
each ("StackOverflow", func);

function func2 (x) { console.log(x); }; //classic function
each ("StackOverflow", func2);

each ("StackOverflow", alert); //YEEEES

each ("StackOverflow", 
    console.log.bind(console)); //here you should bind it to console!
```

Comment: Strictly, an "anonymous function" is a function expression with no name. Function expressions aren't declared, they are only evaluated.

Comment: Your last example won't work obviously, because `console.log` needs the proper context; see also my answer.

Comment: @Jack Obviously yes. I better go to sleep. Upvoted your answer :).

Comment: @BernaMariano Binds the function to a certain context (`this` will always point to `console` inside the function). [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: the 3rd one? `each ("StackOverflow", alert);`

Comment: @BernaMariano `alert` is a function like all the others (`window.alert` actually), and it expects one parameter, so it can be simply used here.

Comment: it doesn't need to be a `function(){ alert() }`

Comment: @BernaMariano Try it ;). You have to pass a function. Any function.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (each in haystack)
```

If you expect `haystack` to be an array, you should iterate it with a for-loop instead of enumerating keys with a for-loop (see [JavaScript for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242841/1048572) for the difference). This is especially true if you iterate strings, and please notice that older IEs do not support bracket notation on strings.

> we can't have a callback function without declaring an anonymous function

No. For a callback function, of course we need some function. But it does not necessarily need to be an anonymous function expression. In your example, you could just do

```
each ("StackOverflow", console.log);
each ("StackOverflow", console.log.bind(console)); // for Chrome users
```

…or pass any other suitable function that you have declared elsewhere.

Strings (like in [this library](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)) might be even shorter sometimes, but they would need to be `eval`ed which is evil for this purpose. Unfortunately EcmaScript does not support any shorter lambda expressions, however you might want to have a look at [FF-only JavaScript 1.8 *expression closures*](http://perfectionkills.com/a-closer-look-at-expression-closures/) or [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)'s minimalist function syntax.

Comment: +1 for the `for..in` warning. You can never repeat it enough times.

Comment: You can't use `console.log` as a callback like that; see also my answer.

Comment: @Jack: In most browsers you can. As you probably will use this code only for testing, it shouldn't matter :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are exactly <strike>two</strike> four ways to create a function in ECMAScript

1. A [FunctionDeclaration](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13)
2. A [FunctionExpression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.5)
3. The Function constructor [called as a function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.1.1)
4. The Function constructor [called as a constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1)

All require the use of the string "function" or "Function".

Comment: Theoretically you could use the `Function()` constructor also, but we are at using `eval()` again.

Answer (score 2):

To use `console.log` as a callback directly, you have to make sure to bind it back to `console` lest it loses the correct execution context, at least in Chrome so I'm told :)

```
each([1, 2, 3], console.log.bind(console));
```

Also, your `each()` doesn't work safely with that `for ... in`:

```
for (var i = 0, n = haystack.length; i != n; ++i) {
    callback(haystack[i]);
}
```

The difference is more obvious when extra properties have been added to an `Array` object.

See also: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Comment: @bažmegakapa Merged into answer :) thanks!