# Remove numbers from strings in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var array = ["0CS", "0CR", "1CR", "1AR"]
```

And I want to remove the numbers from each of the strings so it becomes:

```
["CS","CR","CR","AR"]
```

Is there a more efficient approach than this (purely in JS)?

```
var noNumberArray = []
for(var item in array){
    noNumberArray.push(array[item].replace(/\d+/,""));
}
array = noNumberArray;
```

Comment: Using `for` instead of `for-in` will be more efficient, and arguably more correct. Also, you're not changing the Array. You're creating a new array. This can make a difference in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple for loop without using an extra array is the (unsurprising) winner of the performance test.

http://jsperf.com/nate-array-manipulation

```
for (var i = 0, ln = myArray.length; i < ln; i++) {
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(/\d+/,"");
}
```

Also, changing the property directly rather than creating a new array seems to be more performant (marginally) in all cases but one, according to my test.

`forEach` is next best, `for... in` comes in after that, and `map` is least performant of all.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( var i=0 ; i<array.length ; ++i ) array[i] = array[i].replace(/\d+/,'')

array // ["CS", "CR", "CR", "AR"]
```

Comment: Leaving out braces and semi-colons doesn't really make your code more efficient. Readability is better than fitting on one line.

Comment: @Nate No disagreements there - the main point is that `array` can be edited in-place, rather than using a separate `noNumberArray` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this may help u

```
noNumberArray.push(array[item].replace(/[0-9]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0, ln = array.length; i < ln; i++{
    noNumberArray.push(array[i].replace(/\d+/,""));
}
```

...may be a tiny bit faster for an array.

ref: [JavaScript for...in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["1AB", "AB2", "A3B"];
array = array.map(function(val) { return val.replace(/\d*/g, "");});
```