# jquery plugin development: for in and each confusion

Tags: jquery, plugins, each

when I use these codes, the web is working well:

```
ComOperate.prototype.initop = function()
{
    var op_children = this.$element.find(".mikeoperate").each(function()
   {
   if($(this).attr("data-initstatus") == "hide")
   {
        $(this).hide();
   }
})
```

but if I use these codes,the web crash:

```
var op_children = this.$element.find(".mikeoperate").hide;
for(var pp in op_children)
{
   var p = $(op_children[pp]).attr("data-initstatus");
   if(p == 'hide')
   {
        $(op_children[pp]).hide();
   }
}
```

I don't know why

Comment: `.find(".mikeoperate").hide` is a function reference.... what are you really trying to do here

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript for...in vs for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for)

Comment: from what I can see it should be as simple as `ComOperate.prototype.initop = function () {
    this.$element.find('.mikeoperate[data-initstatus="hide"]').hide();
}`

Comment: sorry, var op_children = this.$element.find(".mikeoperate") shuold be correct. It is a writing mistake. but the web also crash. The question is why I can not visite the web

Answer (score 0):

[hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) is a `function` not `property` and replace `for in` to simple `for` like,

```
var op_children = this.$element.find(".mikeoperate");// remove hide from here
for(var pp=0,len=op_children.length;pp<len;pp++) {
   var p = $(op_children[pp]).attr("data-initstatus");
   if(p == 'hide') {
        $(op_children[pp]).hide();
   }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ECeliVoD/1)

Comment: if use for in the I can not visit web page, but use each I can. why?