# Difference between for vs for var in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

I populate an associative array in PHP and access the array in a JS function. I use json_encode() to convert PHP array to JS array. I use IE 8 to run this application. In some machines with IE 8 for(;;) works but fail in others. In some machines with IE 8 for(var in) works but fail in others. What's the difference between the following code?

```
for (var k = 0; k < ruleList.length; k++){ //do something } 

for (var x in ruleList){ //do something }
```

Comment: Use `for...in` on object and `for` on array.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `for(i in x)` works with both, arrays and objects

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i in x) console.log(x[i]);

var o = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3};
for(var i in o) console.log(o[i]);
```

While `for(;;)` works only with arrays

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) console.log(x[i]);

var o = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3};
for(var i=0; i<o.length; i++) console.log(x[i]); // returns undefined because object o doesn't have property length
```

But you could use `Object.keys` to get array of keys of object

```
var o    = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3};
var keys = Object.keys(o);
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) console.log(o[keys[i]]);
```

Common practice is to use `for(i in x)` for objects and `for(;;)` for arrays

Comment: Thanks. I'm a newbie for php and JS

Answer (score 2):

Like it says in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The **for...in statement** iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

Your first statement is used for an array, while the second is used to get all keys of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Already there are discussions and answers of this question.

Refer [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683259/difference-between-for-loop-and-for-in-loop-in-javascript) to know the difference.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.
>
> The for statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement or a set of statements executed in the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find this before.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays (seriously). So depending on your PHP data you might end with entirely different types, e.g.:

```
<?php
$consecutive_keys = array(
    0 => 'Zero',
    1 => 'One',
    2 => 'Two',
);
$sparse_keys = array(
    5 => 'Five',
    10 => 'Then',
);
$dictionary = array(
    'Foo' => 'Bar',
);

echo json_encode($consecutive_keys) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($sparse_keys) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($dictionary) . PHP_EOL;
```

```
["Zero","One","Two"]     <-- Array
{"5":"Five","10":"Then"} <-- Object
{"Foo":"Bar"}            <-- Object
```

Since JavaScript arrays are a subset of JavaScript objects you'll find that `var x in ruleList` (which loops through object properties) kind of works in both cases, but it won't do what you expect when you have an array.

Comment: Thanks. Good clarification between arrays and objects. It all depends how I create the array in php.