# Looping through a JSON Array gives "undefined" results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON String being parsed (in a `response` var) from AJAX:

*The JSON*

```
{
   "TheArray":[  
      {  
         "AlmostThere": {  
            "whatWeAreLookingFor":"Hello"
         }
      },
      {
        "AlmostThere": {
            "whatWeAreLookingFor":"Goodbye"
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

*The JSON being parsed*

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(response); //response is the string version of the JSON code!
```

**Now, I need to loop into the JSON array, hereby mentioned as `TheArray`**. I do this:

*Looping TheArray*

```
for (var contents in jsonData["TheArray"]) {

}
```

And inside there, we get the value of the `whatWeAreLookingFor` element:

```
for (var contents in jsonData["TheArray"]) {
    console.log(contents.whatWeAreLookingFor + "!");
}
```

*But there is a catch! The console outputs...* `undefined!`. - 
I have tried multiple ways to make this work, such as using `contents["whatWeAreLookingFor"]` and what-not, but I still get the same results.

Comment: [Don't use `for... in` for looping over Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for) - use a regular `for` loop, `forEach`, or `for... of` if you can use ES6.

Comment: Hint: log `contents` inside your loop. It won't be what you expect.

Comment: `for (var contents in jsonData.TheArray) {
    console.log(jsonData.TheArray[contents].AlmostThere.whatWeAreLookingFor + "!");
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to access `AlmostThere`

```
  jsonData.TheArray[i].AlmostThere.whatWeAreLookingFor
```

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.TheArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonData.TheArray[i].AlmostThere.whatWeAreLookingFor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop your array `TheArray` in your way, the `contents` var will become these two objects:

```
{  
     "AlmostThere": {  
        "whatWeAreLookingFor":"Hello"
     }
}
```

and

```
{
    "AlmostThere": {
        "whatWeAreLookingFor":"Goodbye"
    }
}
```

Now you want to access the value with

> contents.whatWeAreLookingFor

but this attribute is undefined for these objects. So your console logs `undefined`. You have to access the value with that:

```
contents.AlmostThere.whatWeAreLookingFor
```

So you get the object `AlmostThere` and select the attribute `whatWeAreLookingFor`.

If your using **jquery** you should use:

```
$.each(jsonData.TheArray, function() {
     console.log(contents.AlmostThere.whatWeAreLookingFor + '!');
});
```

API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

`for... in` iterates over the *keys* of an object. For an array, that means ([approximately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)) the indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

You could use Array.prototype.forEach instead:

```
jsonData.theArray.forEach(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents.AlmostThere.whatWerAreLookingFor);
})
```