# Why keys of object is just first character?

Tags: javascript, object

### How to get values listed in translations object?

I am trying to use *Array destructuring* to get object values.

Even while getting keys javascript won't return full key value such as `getaQuote` instead it turns out just first letters `g`.

**Expected console result would be:**

```
getaQuote : a : Get a Quote: Kostenloses Angebot : Richiedi un preventivo : Teklif Al
uploadFile : b : Upload File: Datei Upload : Datei Upload : Dosya Gönder
```

```js
"use strict";

const translations = {
  getaQuote: {
    loc: "a",
    en: "Get a Quote",
    de: "Kostenloses Angebot",
    it: "Richiedi un preventivo",
    tr: "Teklif Al"
  },
  uploadFile: {
    loc: "b",
    en: "Upload File",
    de: "Datei Upload",
    it: "Datei Upload",
    tr: "Dosya Gönder"
  },
  contacts: { loc: "c", en: "Contacts", de: "Kontakt", it: "Contatti" , tr: "İletişim"}
};
  for (let  [key, value] in translations ) {
    let result = `${key}: ${value.loc} : ${value.en} : ${value.de} : ${value.it}:  ${value.tr}`;
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Comment: `(let  [key, value] in translations )` - the `for..in` loop goes over *keys*, so you get each key and then destructure the first two characters of it. First, you want a `for..of` loop and second, you want to iterate over `Object.entries(translations)`

Comment: See also [What is the difference between ( for… in ) and ( for… of ) statements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29285897) | [JavaScript for…in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242841)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the keys from the object by using a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but the string is destructured with the first two characters.

A destructuing of a string calls the implemented [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) and returns the characters.

```js
const [key, value] = 'get';

console.log(key);
console.log(value);
```

To overcome this, you could iterate the entries of the object and get the destructured pairs with an [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

```js
"use strict";

const translations = {
  getaQuote: {
    loc: "a",
    en: "Get a Quote",
    de: "Kostenloses Angebot",
    it: "Richiedi un preventivo",
    tr: "Teklif Al"
  },
  uploadFile: {
    loc: "b",
    en: "Upload File",
    de: "Datei Upload",
    it: "Datei Upload",
    tr: "Dosya Gönder"
  },
  contacts: { loc: "c", en: "Contacts", de: "Kontakt", it: "Contatti" , tr: "İletişim"}
};
  for (let  [key, value] of Object.entries(translations)) {
    let result = `${key}: ${value.loc} : ${value.en} : ${value.de} : ${value.it}:  ${value.tr}`;
    console.log(result);
  }
```