InDesign ECMAScript: Different results in similar FOR-loops
In the end I'm trying to post a table into a textframe, which I like to select by it's name, but it did not work yet.
// change the active document
app.activeDocument = newDoc;
                
// get all existing textFrames
var allTextFrames = document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();

Playing around I've tried to figure out why I can't select it and stuck with these 2 for-loops, which in my opinion should do the same. Obviously I'm wrong as the FOR...IN-loop only returns one element and the FOR...t-loop returns 27 objects which is the correct amount.
for (var f in allTextFrames) {
    allTextFrames[f].select();
    $.writeln("Textframe: " + f + " Name: " + allTextFrames[f].name);
}

for (var t=0; t < allTextFrames.length; t++) {
    allTextFrames[t].select();
    $.writeln("Textframe: " + t + " Name: " + allTextFrames[t].name);
}


While I haven't touched InDesign since middle-school (long story) but I think you want a for( const f of allTextFrames ) - not for( var f in allTextFrames ).

thanks, yes. Just tried and get this: Eval Error (#9): "Illegal use of reserved word 'const'" in 'C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 19.0\de_DE\Scripts\Scripts Panel\CopyAllTables TEMP.jsx' [95:22] in host 'indesign-19.064 (main)'.

Huh - okay. Turns out InDesign's ECMAScript is based on ES5 (2009) whereas for(of) was introduced in ES6 in 2015. Disregard my earlier comment :)

for..in loop might not work if the properties are not enumerable

I'm looking at InDesign's scripting reference and while I can see document.textFrames I don't see an everyItem() method. Can you shed any light on where/how it's defined? And do you have access to a JS Debugger in InDesign?

"the FOR...IN-loop only returns one element" - what is that element, which f is it printing?

@dai link, but the getElements() isn't defined. correct? Yes, I'm using the JS Debugger, but not very familar yet that's why I'm trying to debug with the console.

@Bergi "Textframe: length Name: undefined"

What if you assign var allTextFrames = Array.from(document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements());?

@trincot Array.from was added in ES6, but InDesign still uses ES5.

it says: Exception has occurred: 24
Array.from is not a function

Then do var allTextFrames = [].slice.apply(document.textFrames.everyItem().getElements());

Or even var allTextFrames = [].slice.apply(document.textFrames);

@trincot great that works! thanks! So do I understand right that I had to create an array by hand?

@Oliver Yes, as expected. length is the only enumerable property that for … in enumerates.

@Dai How is this not a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for explains just fine what the difference between the two syntaxes is and why one doesn't work

@Bergi At the time I voted to reopen it it hadn't yet been established that allTextFrames really was an Array type - I was (then) still trying to find the reference for .everyItem().getElements() just-in-case it returned some other collection-type - and non-Array collection-types are common, e.g. NodeList<T> in HTML's DOM.

I don't understand the question. Just in case, the ancient InDesign's version of Javascript (Extendscript) can't iterate through arrays with condition for (element in arr) { ... }. This condition works only for keys of objects: for (key in obj) { ... }. To iterate arrays you have the only option the classic for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {...}.

That's most likely because the object returned by getElements is not an array and it's properties are not enumerable
We can create something similar using this code:


const arrayLikeNotEnumerable = createNotEnumerableArrayLikeObject()

console.log('not enumerable:')
for (var i in arrayLikeNotEnumerable) {
  console.log(i, arrayLikeNotEnumerable[i])
}

const arrayLikeEnumerable = createEnumerableArrayLikeObject()

console.log('enumerable:')
for (var i in arrayLikeEnumerable) {
  console.log(i, arrayLikeEnumerable[i])
}

function createNotEnumerableArrayLikeObject() {
  var x = {}
  x.length = 10
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 1) {
    Object.defineProperty(x, i, {
      value: i,
      enumerable: false
    })
  }
  
  return x
}

function createEnumerableArrayLikeObject() {
  var x = {}
  x.length = 10
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 1) {
    Object.defineProperty(x, i, {
      value: i,
      enumerable: true
    })
  }
  
  return x
}



Output:
not enumerable:
length 10
enumerable:
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
length 10

You can fix that by using [].slice.apply (as trincot suggested)


const arrayLikeNotEnumerable = createNotEnumerableArrayLikeObject()

for (var i in [].slice.apply(arrayLikeNotEnumerable)) {
  console.log(i, arrayLikeNotEnumerable[i])
}

function createNotEnumerableArrayLikeObject() {
  var x = {}
  x.length = 10
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 1) {
    Object.defineProperty(x, i, {
      value: i,
      enumerable: false
    })
  }
  
  return x
}




thx @Konrad this is very helpful
