# Function to convert an Array to an Associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert flat array [k1,v1,k2,v2] to object {k1:v1,k2:v2} in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751034/convert-flat-array-k1-v1-k2-v2-to-object-k1v1-k2v2-in-javascript)

I want to convert an array to an associative array in JavaScript.

For example, given the following input,

```
  var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

I want to get the next associative array as output:

```
  {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean to an Object? Do you want the array members to be the keys or values?

Comment: Well... It's an associative array, but uses number like key. It's similar to: `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}`

Comment: Yes. Exactly, I want them as key => value pair's

Comment: @DavidRodrigues But 0 based, not 1 based!

Comment: Arrays start at `0` and also have `.length`.

Comment: Actually I want above array to be converted into  var a = ['a':'b', 'c':'d'];

Comment: Edit your question with those details!

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Now that you've decided what your question is, update the original post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var obj_a = {};
a.forEach(function(val, i) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) return; // Skip all even elements (= odd indexes)
    obj_a[val] = a[i + 1];   // Assign the next element as a value of the object,
                             // using the current value as key
});
// Test output:
JSON.stringify(obj_a);       // {"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about array.forEach(). Does it work across all browsers?

Comment: @gintas: Only in those supporting ES5. But you can easily provide your own implementation.

Comment: Ohh thats great. But y are you doing JSON.stringify(obj_a);  ?

Comment: @gintas "All modern browsers but IE." [citation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156696/which-web-browsers-natively-support-array-foreach)

Comment: @ROB W if you can give the exact implementation in pure javascript..

Comment: @MurtazaHussain In the source which I linked, a fallback is provided: See MDN: [`.forEach` #Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility). I am using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as a quick method to check whether the object contains the desired name-key pairs.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i += 2) {
  obj[a[i]] = a[i+1];
}
```

Comment: `a.length` would be sufficient since you're jumping in steps of 2 anyway.

Comment: @pimvdb Doing so would be incorrect - consider an array of length 1...

Comment: @rich.okelly Then it would be `{'a': undefined}`, which is probably better than forgetting the key.

Comment: I'd warn against presence checks like `if (obj["foo"])...` or even `if ("foo" in obj)...`, since these will also detect fields found on the `obj`'s prototype (try `if ("toString" in obj)...` as an example). To be on the safe side, use `obj.hasOwnProperty("foo")` - this guarantees that the prototype will not be checked.

Comment: But then again it doesn't really make sense to convert an array with an odd number of elements into such an object, because there aren't clear pairs in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an associative array, they're called `Object`s but do pretty much the same :-)

Here's how you would do the conversion

```
 var obj = {}; // "associative array" or Object
 var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
 for(index in a) {
     if (index % 2 == 0) {
         var key = a[index];
         var val = a[index+1];
         obj[key] = val;
     }
 }
```