# JavaScript find json value

Tags: javascript, json

I need to search inside a json list of countries. The json is like:

```
[ 
{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
{"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
{"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
]
```

I get from database only the code and would output the entire name. So if I get "AL" I would like to retrieve from json "Albania"

Comment: FWIW that's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object.

Comment: This is not elance, please provide examples of what you have tried.

Comment: @BradChristie The code *is* valid JSON.

Comment: @ComFreek: No, JSON is a _Serialized_ format (thus the _N_ for _Notation_).

Comment: @BradChristie Maybe I misunderstood your comment, but [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) verifies the correct format.

Comment: @BradChristie: Can you point out which part is not a valid JSON? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @ComFreek: Take the OP's object, assign it to a variable and call `JSON.stringify(obj)` on it (and view the result). _that_ is JSON. Not to argue semantics, but unless that entire thing was surrounded by quotation marks, it's not _actually_ JSON (as it's easily placed directly in to JS without any further parsing).

Comment: @BradChristie: Look at http://json.org, I can't see any quotation marks around... :)

Comment: That is valid JSON Format

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
var obj = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
];

// the code you're looking for
var needle = 'AL';

// iterate over each element in the array
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
  if (obj[i].code == needle){
     // we found it
    // obj[i].name is the matched result
  }
}
```

Comment: As I stated, it is correct. But just try imagine this list with 100.000 items.

Comment: @Tropicalista In fact, you should move the filter logic to your database engine! The DB will always be the fastest when it comes to filtering, ordering or grouping (assuming you set correct indices).

Comment: @ivoszz: Except that [`Array.forEach`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156696/which-web-browsers-natively-support-array-foreach) can be temperamental when it comes to compatibility.

Comment: It's missing a coma: for (var i = 0; i < obj.length **;** i++){

Comment: Could use find, filter in a loop rather!

Comment: @jaibalaji not if you support IE. Also keep in mind this post is now going on 5 years old, [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) has changed.

Answer (score 143):

I suggest using JavaScript's Array method [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to identify an element by value. It filters data by using a "function to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.."

The following function filters the data, returning data for which the callback returns `true`, i.e. where `data.code` equals the requested country code.

```
function getCountryByCode(code) {
  return data.filter(
      function(data){ return data.code == code }
  );
}

var found = getCountryByCode('DZ');
```

See the demonstration below:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "code": "AF"
}, {
  "name": "Åland Islands",
  "code": "AX"
}, {
  "name": "Albania",
  "code": "AL"
}, {
  "name": "Algeria",
  "code": "DZ"
}];


function getCountryByCode(code) {
  return data.filter(
    function(data) {
      return data.code == code
    }
  );
}

var found = getCountryByCode('DZ');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = found[0].name;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMQ7c/1/).

Comment: I know this is answer is over 5 years old, but the statement that it return "only the value for which the callback returns true" is incorrect. It returns an **array** of **objects** where the value in each matched object causes the callback to return true.  Your code does recognise this, but I feel the statement is misleading

Answer (score 63):

Just use the ES6 [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function in a functional way:

```js
var data=[{name:"Afghanistan",code:"AF"},{name:"Åland Islands",code:"AX"},{name:"Albania",code:"AL"},{name:"Algeria",code:"DZ"}];

let country = data.find(el => el.code === "AL");
// => {name: "Albania", code: "AL"}
console.log(country["name"]);
```

or Lodash **[_.find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find)**:

```js
var data=[{name:"Afghanistan",code:"AF"},{name:"Åland Islands",code:"AX"},{name:"Albania",code:"AL"},{name:"Algeria",code:"DZ"}];

let country = _.find(data, ["code", "AL"]);
// => {name: "Albania", code: "AL"}
console.log(country["name"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 20):

First convert this structure to a "dictionary" object:

```
dict = {}
json.forEach(function(x) {
    dict[x.code] = x.name
})
```

and then simply

```
countryName = dict[countryCode]
```

For a list of countries this doesn't matter much, but for larger lists this method guarantees the instant lookup, while the naive searching will depend on the list size.

Comment: um? countryName = dict[code], 
surely?  or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not at all sure it's true that _"this method guarantees the instant lookup"_. Is there any guarantee that the implementation does anything but a sequential lookup? If not, can we be certain that no significant browser implementation does a sequential lookup?

Comment: @Auspex This answer is relevant to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225058/363217

Answer (score 13):

Making more general the [@showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254067/6904888) answer.

```
var getObjectByValue = function (array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(function (object) {
        return object[key] === value;
    });
};
```

Example:

```
getObjectByValue(data, "code", "DZ" );
```