# Creating a new array of objects by finding values in JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Not sure I can do this but what I'm trying to do is create a new array by searching through some JSON data to find a key and taking the whole object into the new array if the key is found. Below is a sample of the data I am using.

```
{
  "students": {
    "AB10001": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "english"],
    }
    "AB10002": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["maths"],
    }
    "AB10003": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["english"],
    }
    "AB10004": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    }
    "AB10005": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["maths", "science"],
    }
    "AB10006": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["science"],
    }
    "AB10007": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["science"],
    }
    "AB10008": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["science", "history"],
    }
    "AB10009": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    }
    "AB10010": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "maths"],
    }
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is search through the students key of `subjects` for all students who do `history` and then create another array from that, taking the whole student, while leaving the original object the same.

So I want to end up with something that like this:

```
{
  "historyStudents": {
    "AB10001": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "english"],
    }
    "AB10004": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    }
    "AB10008": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["science", "history"],
    }
    "AB10009": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    }
    "AB10010": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "maths"],
    }
  }
}
```

Any insights or assistance would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I'd help you. Can you give me some more context? I see your keywords include javascript. Is this your language of choice to consume the json and search it and produce the new JSon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce()` to create new object with only students with `history` subject.

```js
var data = {"students":{"AB10001":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history","english"]},"AB10002":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["maths"]},"AB10003":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["english"]},"AB10004":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["history"]},"AB10005":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["maths","science"]},"AB10006":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["science"]},"AB10007":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["science"]},"AB10008":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["science","history"]},"AB10009":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history"]},"AB10010":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history","maths"]}}}

var result = {
 historyStudents: Object.keys(data.students)
  .reduce(function(r, e) {
    if(data.students[e].subjects.includes('history')) r[e] = data.students[e]
    return r;
   }, {})
 }

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, this was similar to the route I was trying although this method produced the same result as I was getting. The issue with them results was that the student ID was not being sent into the new object. If you compare the result you are getting to the desired result I wanted, its similar, but not the same.

Comment: @NenadVracar Yes now it returns the exact result, the right thing was to loop over the `keys` .

Answer (score 1):

You need just to loop over the `data.students` keys using `Object.keys()` and for each one check if the relative object value has `history` in its `subjetcs` array:

```
var result = {
  "historyStudents": {}
};

Object.keys(data.students).forEach(function(k) {
  if (data.students[k].subjects.indexOf("history") > -1) {
    result.historyStudents[k] = data.students[k];
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  "students": {
    "AB10001": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "english"],
    },
    "AB10002": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["maths"],
    },
    "AB10003": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["english"],
    },
    "AB10004": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    },
    "AB10005": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["maths", "science"],
    },
    "AB10006": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["science"],
    },
    "AB10007": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["science"],
    },
    "AB10008": {
      "campus": "asd",
      "subjects": ["science", "history"],
    },
    "AB10009": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history"],
    },
    "AB10010": {
      "campus": "cda",
      "subjects": ["history", "maths"],
    }
  }
};
var result = {
  "historyStudents": {}
};

Object.keys(data.students).forEach(function(k) {
  if (data.students[k].subjects.indexOf("history") > -1) {
    result.historyStudents[k] = data.students[k];
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the keys, filter it and build a new object out of the key and the values. Then use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for creating a single object.

```js
function getStudents(object, subject) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .keys(object)
        .filter(k => object[k].subjects.includes(subject))
         .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }))
    );
}


var object = { students: { AB10001: { campus: "cda", subjects: ["history", "english"] }, AB10002: { campus: "asd", subjects: ["maths"] }, AB10003: { campus: "asd", subjects: ["english"] }, AB10004: { campus: "asd", subjects: ["history"] }, AB10005: { campus: "cda", subjects: ["maths", "science"] }, AB10006: { campus: "asd", subjects: ["science"] }, AB10007: { campus: "cda", subjects: ["science"] }, AB10008: { campus: "asd", subjects: ["science", "history"] }, AB10009: { campus: "cda", subjects: ["history"] }, AB10010: { campus: "cda", subjects: ["history", "maths"] } } },
    result = { historyStudents: getStudents(object.students, 'history') };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers you can also es6 `destructuring` to get the desired result

```
const  data = {"students":{"AB10001":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history","english"]},"AB10002":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["maths"]},"AB10003":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["english"]},"AB10004":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["history"]},"AB10005":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["maths","science"]},"AB10006":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["science"]},"AB10007":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["science"]},"AB10008":{"campus":"asd","subjects":["science","history"]},"AB10009":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history"]},"AB10010":{"campus":"cda","subjects":["history","maths"]}}}

const historyStudents = {};
for(const stdId in data.students) {

  // es6 destructuring
  const { subjects } = data.students[stdId];

  if(subjects.includes('history')){
    historyStudents[stdId] = data.students[stdId]; 
  }
}
// object property shorthand
console.log({ historyStudents });
```