# Find in JSON array by manually entered ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my angularjs app I get JSON object from API. 
I have an input field, where I can input ID manually, and if an item with this ID exists, I need to change his property.
I also store this ID to sessionStorage, so when user refresh page, he get value like before refresh.

Here is json from API where I need to change ON THE FLY property SHOW to true if exist

```
$scope.tableParams.data = [
 {id: 1015, type: "ssss", show: false},
 {id: 1016, type: "ssss", show: false},
 {id: 1017, type: "ssss", show: false},
 {id: 1018, type: "ssss", show: false}
]
```

Function for getting input value and store to session storage, and also change SHOW property

```
$scope.getIndex = function (indexOfRow) { //indexOfRow is passed data from input field
       //here I want to change show to true for passed id 

        sessionStorage.setItem("indexOfOpenedRow", JSON.stringify(indexOfRow));
    }
```

I try answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value) but not working for me

I also try this, but allways get `undefined`

```
function findId(array, id) {
        var i, found, obj;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
          obj = array[i];
          if (obj.id == id) {
            console.log(obj);
            return obj;
          }
        }
        return undefined; // <= You might consider null or undefined here
      }
$scope.getIndex = function (indexOfRow) { //indexOfRow is passed data from input field
       //here I want to change show to true for passed id 
        angular.forEach($scope.tableParams.data, function(key, value){
            var result = findId(key.id, indexOfRow);
            console.log(result);
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("indexOfOpenedRow", JSON.stringify(indexOfRow));
    }
```

Comment: Your findId function expects an array and an integer as its parameters. `findId(key.id, indexOfRow);` This makes it look like you're passing two integers into it. I would expect something like `findId( $scope.tableParams.data, indexOfRow );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the function you are searching for. As i understood your question by reading your code you want to compare an seperate ID with the ID in the JSON? If I am wrong commend here and I will edit the answer:

```
function findIDAndSetShowingTrue(array, id) {
    return array.filter(curr=> curr.id === id).map(curr => ({...curr, show: true}));
}
```

- The filter function iterates over every child inside the array and gives you the specific value (*array.filter*).
- Then you can use this child and compare it like an if statement with some other values (*current*).
- In the end you compare current.id and your input id (*current.id === id*) and return the **current** object if it's true.

Comment: this is true. Pls, can you help me now how to on this way change property SHOW to true? For this returned id

Comment: check out [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I'd think it is more suitable for this case.

Comment: @Thomas thank you, find is first thing I try, but not working for me in this case

Comment: @Arter - now the answer should solve your problem - If you also need the old array objects with the show values == false you need to use the same syntax I am using in the map: (...curr, show: true). This is called the spread operator and with this you can combine two arrays - It works like a Object.assing.