# React: Filtering in a search box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement filtering on data I got from an API. 
Here is what I tried:

```
class ApiComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pizzas: [],
      input: "",
    };
  }
  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("api/pizzas").then((Response) => {
      this.setState({
        pizzas: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Response.data)),
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const list = this.state.pizzas
      .filter((d) => this.state.input === "" || d === this.state.input)
      .map((d, index) => <li key={index}>{d}</li>);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form>
          <input
            value={this.state.input}
            type="text"
            onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}
            placeholder="search"
          />
        </form>
        {this.state.pizzas.map((pizza) => (
          <ul key={pizza.id}>
            {pizza.area_id} &emsp;{pizza.name}&emsp;
            {pizza.real_name}
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to input anything in my searchbox, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: d.includes is not a function

II'm using es6. So includes should be there.

Comment: Is the axios' response.data is array ?

Comment: try to replace 'd.includes(this.state.input)' to 'd===this.state.input'

Comment: No.It is Json Data

Comment: @kahonmlg code doesn't give any error. But it doesn't do any filtering either.

Comment: can you do a console.log(d) and console.log(this.state.input) inside the filter to see the values?

Comment: @mage456 includes is for arrays not for JSON objects. it looks like you are not comparing the value in the JSON propelly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined @kahonmlg

Comment: try to type return in the find, .filter((d) => { return (this.state.input === "" || d.includes(this.state.input)) })

Comment: Updated to code to convert the response to array @kahonmlg

Comment: @mage456 could you write the object that you obtain in this.state.pizzas to see if you are comparing fine?

Comment: Please post the output the data of `console.log(Response.data)` and let us know what are you getting from API

Comment: [{"id":1,"real_name":"pizzahut","area_id":1},{"id":2,"real_name":"pizzaInn","area_id":2},{"id":3,"real_name":"pastaPalace","area_id":2}]
@kahonmlg

Comment: @mage456 .filter((d) => { return (d.real_name === text.state.input) }).