# Compare and Array to an array of objects and return a part of the matched objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects below

```
const response = 
[
{
    id: 105,
    label: 'test',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/500' ]
  },
  {
    id: 337,
    label: 'test2',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/766' ]
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    label: 'test20',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/95' ]
  }
]
```

And I have an array called directories

```
directories = [ '/api/1/directories/766', '/api/1/directories/95' ]
```

I am trying to search/filter response to only return the ids of objects that matches the directories in directories array

so the sample output can be something like below, which is only the IDs of the matched objects

```
sampleOut= [337, 200]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript find json value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and check exist by `indexOf` as

```js
const response = 
[
{
    id: 105,
    label: 'test',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/500' ]
  },
  {
    id: 337,
    label: 'test2',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/766' ]
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    label: 'test20',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/95' ]
  }
]

directories = [ '/api/1/directories/766', '/api/1/directories/95' ];

var result = response.reduce((acc, item)=>{

  if(directories.indexOf(item.directories[0]) > -1){
    acc.push(item.id);
    
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

Comment: never mind it worked the array was declared empty first after I filled it in I got the right data

Answer (score 3):

This could be done as follows:

```
const out = response.filter(o => directories.includes(o.directories[0])).map(o => o.id);
```

Please have a look at the following runnable code snippet.

```js
const response = [
  {
    id: 105,
    label: 'test',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/500' ]
  },
  {
    id: 337,
    label: 'test2',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/766' ]
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    label: 'test20',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/95' ]
  }
];

const directories = [ '/api/1/directories/766', '/api/1/directories/95' ];

const out = response.filter(o => directories.includes(o.directories[0])).map(o => o.id);
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const sampleOut = response.filter(response => directories.includes(response.directories[0]))
    .map(response => response.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```js
const response = 
[
{
    id: 105,
    label: 'test',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/500' ]
  },
  {
    id: 337,
    label: 'test2',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/766' ]
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    label: 'test20',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/95' ]
  }
];

const directories = [ '/api/1/directories/766', '/api/1/directories/95' ];

const res = response.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  if(directories.includes(elem.directories[0])){
    acc.push(elem.id)
  }
  return acc
},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the main array and pushing the propertie you want if there is a match:

```js
const response = 
[
{
    id: 105,
    label: 'test',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/500' ]
  },
  {
    id: 337,
    label: 'test2',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/766' ]
  },
  {
    id: 200,
    label: 'test20',
    directories: [ '/api/1/directories/95' ]
  }
]

var directories = [ '/api/1/directories/766', '/api/1/directories/95' ]

var sampleOut = []

response.forEach(function(a) {
  if (directories.indexOf(a.directories[0]) >= 0 ) {
    sampleOut.push(a.id)
  }
})

console.log(sampleOut)
```